# Present initial viewcontroller animated after launch screen

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have searched the forums but couldn't seem to find an answer for my question.
I want the initial viewcontroller to appear animated(beeing faded in) after the launch screen. Is this possible? If yes, could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You should to it the other way around - display a ImageView containing your launch screen image and fade that ImageView out.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I tried at first but the problem is that my views are all in a navigation controller and if I put an ImageView the size of my screen the navigation bar will still be visible

Comment: Add it to the Window, not to your view.

Comment: That solved my question,great idea, please post it as an answer so I can mark it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to it the other way around - display a `UIImageView` containing your launch screen image and fade that `UIImageView` out after the launch.

Note that you should add the `UIImageView` to the `UIWindow`, not the `UIView` of your controller to place it above everything else.